# nth-of-type(2n) selects starting from the first element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following html:

```
<section class="post-content">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/300?image=5" alt="kitten">
    <p>
      Some text...
    </p>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200?image=6" alt="kitten">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300?image=7" alt="kitten"> [to have rounded corners]
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/400?image=8" alt="kitten">
    <p>
      Some other text...
    </p>
  </section>
```

I want to round the corners of the every second image that comes after a paragraph. To achieve this, I have this CSS rule:

```
p~img:not(:first-of-type):nth-of-type(2n){
    border-radius: 10%;
}
```

For some reason, it selects the first (*image=6*) and the third image (*image=8*) not the middle one. It works fine when I pass 2n+1 instead of 2n. But, I just cannot get it why it works this way. This was the behaviour as well before adding `:not(:first-of-type)` part.

Any help?

Comment: the :not() will not exclude the first image from the counting, it will simply exclude it from the selection

Comment: @TemaniAfif I got it! Then how can I exclude it? I want to see if I can use 2n.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question! The solution might be in another post, but the question is not duplicate!

Comment: take the time to read carefully the duplicate. It's a duplicate and your answer/explanation is there (SPOIL: you cannot do it with CSS actually)

Answer (score 0):

Both options below work the following way...

According to [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp):

> The general sibling selector (i.e., `~`) selects all elements that are next
> siblings of a specified element.

So, if you add `p ~ img:nth-child(even)` or `p ~ img:nth-child(2n)` it means that only images that are siblings of a `<p>` tag will be selected. If you want the second image after a `<p>` tag to have rounded borders, this is the third image in general, **but it's the second sibling of a `<p>` tag**.

**OPTION 1**

```css
p ~ img:nth-child(even) {
  border-radius: 10%;
}
```

```html
<section class="post-content">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/300?image=5" alt="kitten">
  <p>
    Some text...
  </p>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200?image=6" alt="kitten">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300?image=7" alt="kitten"> [to have rounded corners]
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/400?image=8" alt="kitten">
  <p>
    Some other text...
  </p>
</section>
```

**OPTION 2**

```css
p ~ img:nth-child(2n) {
  border-radius: 10%;
}
```

```html
<section class="post-content">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/300?image=5" alt="kitten">
  <p>
    Some text...
  </p>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200?image=6" alt="kitten">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300?image=7" alt="kitten"> [to have rounded corners]
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/400?image=8" alt="kitten">
  <p>
    Some other text...
  </p>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit? So, nth-child(even) will select the 2nd, 4th, etc elements, right? Then how not(:first-child) fits here?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You don't need `:not(:first-child)`.